# Asignar un valor con lógica a un modelo en django

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django, django-models, lógica

Tengo mi modelo en django y quiero que una de la variables del modelo que es 'porcentaje' multiplique un porcentaje del modelo 'valor' y 'porcentaje' sea ese resultado pero ' porcentaje también es un modelo, es una columna de mi base de datos que necesito que su contenido sea esa operación, adjunto código

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import  MinValueValidator

class venta(models.Model):
valor = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1000.0)])

#falta signar el modelo 'porcentaje' con la operación que sería (valor * 0.03)
```

Comment: Hola Sharik, bienvenido a [es.so]. Deberías [edit] y mostrar el código que has probado, como ejemplo de lo que estás explicando, así como realizar una pregunta **concreta** sobre el error o dificultad que estás teniendo con dicho código. Te invito a realizar el [tour] y que visites [ask] para aprender a realizar un [example]. Recibirás más respuestas, y de calidad, si la pregunta está correctamente redactada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un método en tu modelo "venta" para realizar la operación y asignar el resultado a la variable "porcentaje":

```
class venta(models.Model):
valor = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1000.0)])
porcentaje = models.FloatField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.porcentaje = self.valor * 0.03
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

De esta manera, cada vez que se guarde un objeto de la clase "venta", se realizará la operación y se asignará el resultado a la variable "porcentaje".

Si lo que quieres es que se calcule el porcentaje cada vez que se accede al atributo, puedes definir una propiedad en el modelo:

```
class venta(models.Model):
valor = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1000.0)])

@property
def porcentaje(self):
    return self.valor * 0.03
```

Asi, cada vez que accedas al atributo "porcentaje" del objeto "venta", se calculará automáticamente el porcentaje.